# How to refact UPDATE via SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, database, refactoring

I have this structure of my db:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `peoples` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

For customers.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `peoplesaddresses` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `people_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

For their addresses.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `peoplesphones` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `people_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

For their phones.

**UPD4**

```
ALTER TABLE peoplesaddresses DISABLE KEYS; 
ALTER TABLE peoplesphones DISABLE KEYS; 

ALTER TABLE peoplesaddresses ADD INDEX i_phone (phone);
ALTER TABLE peoplesphones ADD INDEX i_phone (phone);
ALTER TABLE peoplesaddresses ADD INDEX i_address (address);
ALTER TABLE peoplesphones ADD INDEX i_address (address);

ALTER TABLE peoplesaddresses ENABLE KEYS;
ALTER TABLE peoplesphones ENABLE KEYS;
```

**END UPD4**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `people_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `adress` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;

INSERT INTO `order` (`id`, `people_id`, `name`, `phone`, `adress`) VALUES
(1, 0, 'name1', 'phone1', 'address1'),
(2, 0, 'name1_1', 'phone1', 'address1_1'),
(3, 0, 'name1_1', 'phone1', 'address1_2'),
(4, 0, 'name2', 'phone2', 'address2'),
(5, 0, 'name2_1', 'phone2', 'address2_1'),
(6, 0, 'name3', 'phone3', 'address3'),
(7, 0, 'name4', 'phone4', 'address4'),
(8, 0, 'name1_1', 'phone5', 'address1_1'),
(9, 0, 'name1_1', 'phone5', 'address1_2'),
(11, 0, 'name1', 'phone1', 'address1'),
(10, 0, 'name1', 'phone1', 'address1');
```

Production base have over 9000 records. Is there way to execute this 3 update query's little more faster, than now (~50 min on dev machine).

```
INSERT INTO peoplesphones( phone, address ) 
SELECT DISTINCT `order`.phone, `order`.adress
FROM `order` 
GROUP BY `order`.phone;
```

Fill peoplesphones table with unique phones

```
INSERT INTO peoplesaddresses( phone, address ) 
SELECT DISTINCT `order`.phone, `order`.adress
FROM `order` 
GROUP BY `order`.adress;
```

Fill peoplesaddresses table with unique adress.
The next three querys are very slow:

```
UPDATE peoplesaddresses, peoplesphones SET peoplesaddresses.people_id = peoplesphones.id WHERE peoplesaddresses.phone = peoplesphones.phone;

UPDATE peoplesaddresses, peoplesphones SET peoplesphones.people_id = peoplesaddresses.people_id WHERE peoplesaddresses.address = peoplesphones.address;

UPDATE `order`, `peoplesphones` SET `order`.people_id = `peoplesphones`.people_id where `order`.phone = `peoplesphones`.phone;
```

Finally fill people table, and clear uneccessary fields.

```
INSERT INTO peoples( id, name ) 
SELECT DISTINCT `order`.people_id, `order`.name
FROM `order` 
GROUP BY `order`.people_id;

ALTER TABLE `peoplesphones`
  DROP `address`;

ALTER TABLE `peoplesaddresses`
  DROP `phone`;
```

So, again: How can I make those UPDATE query's a little more faster? THX.

**UPD:** I forgott to say: I need to do it at once, just for migrate phones and adresses into other tables since one people can have more than one phone, and can order pizza not only at home.

**UPD2:**

[image: MySQL Variables]
**UPD3:**

Replace slow update querys on this (without with) get nothing.

```
UPDATE  peoplesaddresses
LEFT JOIN
        peoplesphones
ON      peoplesaddresses.phone = peoplesphones.phone
SET     peoplesaddresses.people_id = peoplesphones.id;

UPDATE  peoplesphones
LEFT JOIN
        `peoplesaddresses`
ON      `peoplesaddresses`.address = `peoplesphones`.address
SET     `peoplesphones`.people_id = `peoplesaddresses`.people_id;

UPDATE  `order`
LEFT JOIN
        `peoplesphones`
ON      `order`.phone = `peoplesphones`.phone
SET     `order`.people_id = `peoplesphones`.people_id;
```

**UPD4** After adding code at the top (upd4), script takes a few seconds for execute. But on ~6.5k query it terminate with text: "The system cannot find the Drive specified".

Thanks to All. Especially to xQbert and Brent Baisley.

Comment: +1 Very good question. I have to say this explicitly.

Comment: +1 for well laid out question.  one way to go faster would be to have the db turn off logging/index updates then turn them back on when done and force a refresh of indexes after complete.  I'll spend a few minutes looking up the syntax.

Comment: May want to consider the use of bulk inserts if possible too.  [Docs - Speed up inserts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html)  I'd post options but w/o testing that link covers what I would try.

Comment: Per previous comment: here's the syntax: You can also disable or enable the nonunique indexes for a MyISAM table by using the following statements rather than myisamchk. If you use these statements, you can skip the FLUSH TABLE operations:

`ALTER TABLE tbl_name DISABLE KEYS;
ALTER TABLE tbl_name ENABLE KEYS;`  (source from above link comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

50 minutes for 9000 records is a bit ridiculous, event without indexes. You might as well put the 9000 records in Excel and do what you need to do. I think there is something else going on  with your dev machine. Perhaps you have mysql configured to use very little memory? Maybe you can post the results of this "query":

```
show variables like "%size%";
```

Just this morning I did an insert(ignore)/select on 2 tables (one into another), both with over 400,000 records. 126,000 records were inserted into the second table, it took a total of 2 minutes 13 seconds.

I would say put indexes on any of the fields you are joining or grouping on, but this seems like a one time job. I don't think the lack of indexes is your problem.

Comment: Your join_buffer_size is set to 128K, (131072/1024), key_buffer_size is 16MB, myisam_sort_buffer_size is 8MB. You should at least triple those settings. A regular desktop or laptop can easily handle those settings. For a simple fix, switch to the my-large.cnf settings file. "large" is defined as up to 512MB.

Answer (score 2):

1. All write operations are slow in relational databases. Especially indexes make them slow, since they have to be recalculated.
2. If you're using a `WHERE` in your statements, you should place an index on the fields referenced.
3. `GROUP BY` is always very slow, and so is `DISTINCT`, since they have to do a lot of checks that don't scale linearly. Always avoid them.

You may like to choose a different database engine for what you're doing. 9000 records in 50 minutes is very slow. Experiment with a few different engines, such as MyISAM and InnoDB. If you're using temporary tables a lot, MEMORY is really fast for those.

**Update**: Also, updating multiple tables in one statement probably shouldn't be done.

Comment: +1 I could consider it a good answer and learnt something new that I never knew before.

Comment: > 3. GROUP BY is always very slow, and so is DISTINCT, since they have to do a lot of checks that don't scale linearly. Always avoid them. .... >>> But I have problem in other querys.